# Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/sopcast/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

I don't know why I keep receiving the following error messages, when running `apt-get update`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/sopcast/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/sopcast/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do either with the Internet connection or administrator  permission.

1. Try checking connection problems.
2. Try installing as root.

   sudo su

Then in the root terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: You don't need `sudo` in a root prompt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I'm always using root mode. and the connection is ok.

I updated the sources.list and the issue disappeared.